# Email not sending in register controller

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-7

**I trying to send email after successful register but could not send**

here is code of register controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'parentname' => $data['parentname'],
            'relation' => $data['relation'],
            'phonenumber' => $data['phonenumber'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            
        ]);

         $details=[
            'title' => 'title :Check Mail fucntion',
            'body'  => 'test purpose',
        ];

        Mail::to('example.kk49@gmail.com')->send(new WelcomeMail($details));
        return view('mail.thanks');

    }
```

*if i use this mail function in*

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

Then its sending email

Comment: Somehow your email has not been sent. You need to catch the error

Comment: how can i check error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line in your create() method is returning. This means nothing else in the method will execute. You need to catch the results of the User::create() into a variable, perform the rest of the actions, and then return those results.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'city' => $data['city'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'parentname' => $data['parentname'],
        'relation' => $data['relation'],
        'phonenumber' => $data['phonenumber'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        
    ]);

     $details=[
        'title' => 'title :Check Mail fucntion',
        'body'  => 'test purpose',
    ];

    Mail::to('example.kk49@gmail.com')->send(new WelcomeMail($details));

    Mail::to('otheremail@gmail.com')->send(new AdminNewAccount($details));

    return view('mail.thanks');
}
```

Edit: I've updated this to show an example of a second email, and also removed a duplicated return statement.

Comment: it throwing an error and not logging in "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement i.................etc"

Comment: It seems like it got past the registration and is now trying to log the user in. Did it send the email? I believe the email error is fixed and you are on to a new error. What is the full error message, and have you made any modifications to the login process? It might make sense to make a new posting for that error.

Comment: done sir, i am using here  return view('mail.thanks'); which is no useful for me  but now i remove it and its going to dashboard . thanks

Comment: a little help , if i want to send two mails here ? one for admin so how can i do this ?

Comment: You could loop over a list of emails, like this: 


foreach (['example1@gmail.com', 'example2@gmail.com'] as $recipient) {
   Mail::to(recipient)->send(new WelcomeMail($details));
        return view('mail.thanks');
}

I'm pulling that right from the mail documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail  :)

Comment: in that way they got same content  in email , but i need different email for admin to show registered user info, and second email for user for welcome only

Comment: In that case you can add a second Mail::to() statement. I've updated the reply to show an example of that. You will need to have a second mailable, like WelcomeMail, and reference it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the error by `Swift_TransportException`, like this :

```
try {
        Mail::to('example.kk49@gmail.com')->send(new WelcomeMail($details));
} catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) {
        $response = $e->getMessage(); // catch the error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the config for using new configurations.
run the following commands in your terminal.

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```